# java nested for loop spaces and numbers

Tags: java, for-loop

I can't seem to figure out how to figure this problem out.  I want to add a number and remove a space on each line working down from 1.

```
for (int line = 1; line <= 5; line++) {
    for (int space = 5; space >= line + 1; space--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to your problem is recognizing that 5 characters need to be printed on each line.  Each digit is printed the same number of times it represents, with spaces filling in the rest.

```
for (int i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    // print 5 minus i spaces
    for (int j=5; j >= i + 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    // repeat the ith digit i times
    for (int k=0; k < i; ++k) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

**Output:**

```
    1
   22
  333
 4444
55555
```

But note that you could even simplify this further, if you want fewer lines of codes, to this:

```
for (int i=1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    String line = new String(new char[5-i]).replace("\0", " ") +
                  new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", String.valueOf(i));
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim!  Can you please help explain the thought process here.  I can't believe I didn't add another loop.  Super new here.

Comment: The first loop prints `5 - i` spaces, from left to right, and the second loop, on the same line, prints the number `i`, i times, from left to right.  That's it.

Comment: Thanks again Tim!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for (int line = 1; line <= 5; line++) {
        for (int space = 5; space >= line + 1; space--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < line ; k++) {
             System.out.print(line);
        }
        System.out.println("");
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to pass a empty String to println

Comment: @PaulPearson why did you choose this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Just seems strange that @TimBiegeleisen answered the question first, provided more information, provided output, an optional solution, answered OP comments **and** went to the bother of formatting the OP question - very strange